# PDO не правильно выбирает тип

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Написал скрипт, который должен просто вставлять данные в SELECT и возвращать результат:

```
$searchSql = "SELECT * FROM consult AS c LEFT JOIN user AS u ON c.lectorId=u.id WHERE c.date>=NOW() ";
$sqlParams = [];
if (!empty($group)){
    $searchSql .= "AND WHERE `group` LIKE :group";
    $sqlParams[':group'] = "%$group%";
}
if (!empty($discipline)){
    $searchSql .= "AND WHERE `discipline` LIKE :discipline";
    $sqlParams[':discipline'] = "%$discipline%";
}
if (!empty($lector)){
    $searchSql .= "AND WHERE `lector` LIKE :lector";
    $sqlParams[':lector'] = "%$lector%";
}
$stm = $db->prepare($searchSql);
foreach ($sqlParams as $key=>$value){
    $stm->bindValue($key,$value,PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
$stm->execute();
$result = $stm->fetchAll();
```

Запрос, который прилетает в MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM consult AS c LEFT JOIN user AS u ON c.lectorId=u.id WHERE c.date>=NOW() AND WHERE `group` LIKE '%12%'
```

Почему параметр :group был вставлен в одиночные кавычки?

PHP 5.6 MySQL 5.5 (OpenServer 5.2.4)

Comment: В том, что в запросе параметр group был обернут в одинарные кавычки никакой ошибки нет. Ошибка в построении запроса, а конкретнее - во втором WHERE (`AND WHERE`). Запрос выбрасывал ошибку из-за некорректного синтаксиса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Почему параметр :group был вставлен в одиночные кавычки?

Потому, что это не PDO выбирает тип, а вы ему говорите, что все ваши параметры - строчные:

```
$stm->bindValue($key,$value,PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Если вам нужен какой-то другой тип, нужно указывать это явно. Список доступных типов: http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.constants.php

Хотя, судя по тому, что вы используете LIKE %%, всё работает именно так, как должно.

Answer (score 1):

Иначе MySQL посчитает это синтаксической конструкцией и выплюнет ошибку. [Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)

> Nonreserved keywords are permitted as identifiers without quoting.
>   Reserved words are permitted as identifiers if you quote them

Comment: У автора в запросе два слова group в одинарных кавычках, поэтому вы, видимо, перепутали. То, что он обернул название колонки в бэктики говорит о том, что он понимает то, о чём вы написали и спрашивает о другом.